# any work around to allow for an action result to accept a Abstract class as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have different configurations all inheriting from a base configuration that are customized in forms.  I want all of these to be handled by a single action result.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(AbstractBaseConfig config)
    {
        ...do some logic...
        return View("../Home/Index");
    }
```

However, this is not possible because you cannot base in abstract classes as a parameter to an action result.  Is there any work around for this so I don't need a seperate action result for each configuration? (I still want each configuration to be it's own class, I only need access to the base class methods in the action result logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't, and the reason is that MVC will try to do `new AbstractBaseConfig()` as part of the Data Binding process (which parses the URL or the Form Post and puts the results in a concrete object). And by definition, doing `new AbstractBaseConfig()` is impossible for an abstract class.

**It also makes sense for other reasons, I will explain why.**

You seem to expect that **MVC can determine the class *from the parameters that are being passed in***. That is not how it works, in fact the opposite is true: the Action Method has to specify the **exact class**, and then the Binder will instantiate that exact class and try to bind its properties.

Suppose you had this:

```
public abstract class Thing { public int ID { get;set; } }
public class NamedThing : Thing { public string Name { get;set; } }
public class OtherThing : Thing { public string Name { get;set; } }
```

and suppose it would be allowed to use:

```
public IActionResult Register(Thing thing)
```

then what would you expect to be in `thing` after Data Binding: a **`Thing`** object with only the **`ID`** set? Or one of the other object types, with **`Name`** set, but how would MVC ever be able to know which class you meant?

So for all these reasons, this is not possible.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I assumed it wouldn't be possible but just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything before I implemented a different action result for each config.

Comment: FYI for answers that helped, consider upvoting, and possibly even selecting one of them as the Accepted answer.

Comment: Yes its possible if you create a custom `ModelBinder` - the request just needs to include something that identifies which concrete implementation to initialize. Refer [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) to understand the model binding process, which includes some code for an abstract ModelBinder

Answer (score 0):

You could have a base class inherit the abstract class and all your classes inherit from that base class whilst having that base class as your parameter

Take for example

```
public abstract class ABase
{
  public void stuff()
  {
      var stuff = string.Empty;
      stuff = "hello";
  }

  public virtual void otherstuff()
  {
      var stuff = string.Empty;
      stuff = "hello";
  }
}

public class Base : ABase
{
  //empty
}

public class Derived : Base
{
  public void mystuff()
  {
    this.stuff();
  }

  public override void otherstuff()
  {
     // Custom code
  }
}

public ActionResult Register(Base config)
{
}
```

Comment: Hmm, only issue I see with this is I need to override the functions defined in `Base` in each `Derived`

Comment: you don't have to override them if all derived classes do the same thing with the base method, unless they all have a different implementation of the method in the base class

Comment: correct. They all have different implementations.  I have a function `BuildString()` in Base.  Then, in each `Derived` class, it implements this differently based off of properties only in each specific derived classes.

Comment: then the only way to do it is to override them which only makes sense. Make the method virtual in the abstract class and override it in the derived class as in the classes with custom implementations, also see the answer below on why it can't be a parameter